# Unable to create TypeORM DTO in Nest.js with Foreign Key Column

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

DB Entity

```js
@Entity()
export class Estimate {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  estimateId: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Customer, (customer) => customer.customerId)
  customer: Customer;

  @ManyToOne(() => Organization, (organization) => organization.organizationId)
  organization: Organization;

  @ManyToMany(() => Item)
  @JoinTable()
  items: Item[];

  @ManyToMany(() => Tax)
  @JoinTable()
  taxes: Tax[];

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 36 })
  estimateNumber: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 36 })
  orderNumber: string;

  @Column({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  estimateDate: string;

  @Column({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  expiryDate: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 75 })
  salesPersonName: string;

  @Column({ type: 'money' })
  subTotal: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 12 })
  discountType: string;

... trimmed
}
```

My DTO

```js
export class CreateEstimateDto {
  customer: number; // error
  organization: number; // error
  items: number[]; // error
  taxes: number[]; // error
  estimateNumber: string;
  orderNumber: string;
  estimateDate: string;
  expiryDate: string;
  salesPersonName: string;
  subTotal: number;
...trimmed
}
```

service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { CreateEstimateDto } from './dto/create-estimate.dto';
import { UpdateEstimateDto } from './dto/update-estimate.dto';
import { Estimate } from './entities/estimate.entity';

@Injectable()
export class EstimatesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Estimate)
    private estimateRepository: Repository<Estimate>,
  ) {}

  create(createEstimateDto: CreateEstimateDto) {
    return this.estimateRepository.insert(createEstimateDto); // type mismatch
  }
}
```

Getting error

```sh
Argument of type 'CreateEstimateDto' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<Estimate> | QueryDeepPartialEntity<Estimate>[]'.
  Type 'CreateEstimateDto' is not assignable to type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<Estimate>'.
    Types of property 'customer' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type '(() => string) | QueryDeepPartialEntity<Customer>'.ts(2345)
```

The following columns are foreign key columns

customer, organization, items, taxes

**Workaround 1:**

I can make DTO field's type to `any` - that will come as `{}` object in swagger spec

Answer (score 0):

What is actually happening here is that it's trying to convert integer to category type and error happens here. You can fetch foreign relations and then pass it through `insert` method. As I know there is no straight way of doing this in nest.

**Edit**

for example for your customer relation you can do this:

```
const customer = customerRepository.findOne(createEstimateDto.customer);
```

and then pass it to insert method:

```
return this.estimateRepository.insert(Object.assign(createEstimateDto, { customer }));
```

Comment: I can understand what is happening actually, I am looking for a solution past 2 days. :/

Comment: I've updated the answer. check it out

Comment: It is not working @Mohammad, getting similar error